# Magento Custom Module: multiple Image Uploader in adminhtml form

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

i have created adminhtml module it is working fine. in create new item form there are 4 field name , images, url and email id;

i have used file uploader to upload images .  it is working fine  but i am not able to upload multiple images.

is it possible to have multiple image uploader? here is my simple image uploader code.

```
  if(isset($data['image']) && $data['image'] != ''){
        $finderLink = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) .'finder/store_locator/'.$data['image'];
        $finderName = $data['image'];
        $fieldset->addField('imagelabel', 'label', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('finder')->__('Location Image'),
            'name'  =>'image',
            'value'     => $finderLink,
            'after_element_html' => '<img src="'.$finderLink .'" alt=" '. $finderName .'" height="120" width="120" />',
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('image', 'image', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('finder')->__('Change image'),
            'required' => false,
            'name' => 'image',
        ));

    }else{
        $fieldset->addField('image', 'image', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('finder')->__('image'),
            'required' => false,
            'name' => 'image',
        ));
    }
```

[image]

I need help to have multiple image uploader in my custom module.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create your custom renderer for the image field. For this create this class in your module:

```
<?php 
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Adminhtml_[Entity]_Helper_Image extends Varien_Data_Form_Element_Image{
    //make your renderer allow "multiple" attribute
    public function getHtmlAttributes(){
        return array_merge(parent::getHtmlAttributes(), array('multiple'));
    }
}
```

Now at the top of your `_prepareForm` (where you add your fields) add this line before adding any field:

```
$fieldset->addType('image', '[Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Adminhtml_[Entity]_Helper_Image');
```

Or if you want to be "politically correct" add it this way:

```
$fieldset->addType('image', Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName('[module]/adminhtml_[entity]_helper_image'));
```

This will tell Magento that in your current fieldset, all the fields with type `image` should be rendered by your own class.

Now you can add your field like similar to how you did it:

```
$fieldset->addField('image', 'image', array(
            'name'      => 'image[]', //declare this as array. Otherwise only one image will be uploaded
            'multiple'  => 'multiple', //declare input as 'multiple'
            'label'     => Mage::helper('helper_alias')->__('Image'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('helper_alias')->__('Image'),
            'required'  => true,
        ));
```

That's it.
Don't forget to replace the placeholders (`[Module]` and others) with your values.

This is basically the way to override/add any input type you want. Create your own class that should extend the original input class (or `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract` if you add a new one) and declare it at the top of `_prepareForm`

Comment: i have created renderer  with following code.  public function render(Varien_Object $row){if($row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex())==""){        return "";}else{         $html = '<img ';
            $html .= 'id="' . $this->getColumn()->getId() . '" ';
            $html .= 'width="80" ';
            $html .= 'height="80" ';
            $html .= 'src="' . Mage::getBaseUrl("media") .'finder/stre_locator/' . $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex()) . '"';
            $html .= 'class="grid-image ' . $this->getColumn()->getInlineCss() . '"/>';
        }

        return $html;
    }

Comment: what will be [Entity]?

Comment: @JackTorris It is what you are managing. If you are managing articles then it can be `Article`. You can even skip that, but this way you can differentiate between forms.

Comment: @Marius for multiple i have to create separate file button to upload image ? or how it can handle multiple image

Comment: @Marius: as per your answer I'm able to select multiple images but they are not being uploaded. one of the reason seems to be that you have not mentioned the `saveAction()` where the file upload should have been written. can you please add that too in your answer?

Comment: @MohammadFaisal. That's a totally different question. You can loop through all the values in `$_FILES` and check what is uploaded. Or you can ask a separate question about this.

Comment: @Marius I have created one custom module for associate products to specific product by your module creator. Its working rock in local. but when i move into live, i got 404 page in admin. could you give me a suggestion to fix it?

Comment: @DRAJI. what version of the module creator did you use? There is a bug in version 1.6 and lower where if you have a capital letter in the module name it doesn't work on UNIX OS. I mean `Modulename` is ok, `ModuleName` is not. This should be fixed in the 1.9 version that is available here https://github.com/tzyganu/UMC1.9. The support for 1.6 version will end in a few days.

Comment: @Marius Thank you for your response. Yeah, i have used version 1.6. let me check with new version. Thank you

Comment: I used this code. but I'm getting only one image upload field. What am I missing?. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this code in my web application, try it.

```
$fieldset->addField('image', 'image', array(
            'name'      => 'image',
            'multiple'  => 'multiple',
            'mulitple'  => true,
            'label'     => Mage::helper('magentostudy_design')->__('design Image'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('magentostudy_design')->__('design Image'),
            'required'  => true,
            'disabled'  => $isElementDisabled
        ));
```

Comment: 'mulitple' => true //?

Answer (score -1):

i'd have the module that you can download it for free if you wanted.

this is the exhibit.
[image]

Comment: Hi,can you give me the that free module download link

Comment: can you pls send me this type of module  @Josua Marcel Chrisano